# How to handle variables and functions without a true stack

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, processor

I am designing a 8-bit processor, but I don't have all the components yet, so I'm doing some other stuff like the assembler, a Virtual Machine to simulate the programs, and a small higher-level language than assembly.

I don't have any stack and my architecture is based on an accumulator (the only register is the accumulator) but I would like to know how to generate assembly code for the variables and the functions. If there's no real solution, is there still a workaround?

The architecture:
[image: 1]

Comment: Without knowing the details of your instruction set it's hard to say, but making guesses based on your diagram, it looks like you would need to dedicate a memory location as a stack pointer if you want recursive functions.

Comment: I had thought to a stack pointer but the problem is that I can read the value at the pointer's address (via indirect addressing) but I can't write to (I have only immediate addressing available while writing :/)

Comment: If you can't write to an address pointed to in some way by A or a memory location then I don't think there's any practical way of implementing recursive functions. You can implement non-recursive functions by giving each function fixed addresses for storing its return address and its variables.

Comment: Maybe you can emulate indirect writes with a bunch of ugly conditionals.

Comment: An example of "ugly conditionals"?

Comment: It's your architecture, we don't know what instructions you have.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by "conditionals", some jumps, instructions?

Comment: Yes,conditional jumps. `IF` statements if you like ;)

Comment: If you can change the architecture, indirect load/store would be useful for other things than just stack too.

Comment: Answering just the title, most RISC CPUs implement call/return as jump-and-link, using a register to hold the return address (unlike x86 which pushes it onto the stack).  So a `bl` instruction does `LR=PC` (assuming PC is already incremented to point to the next instruction) / `PC = target` (start executing somewhere else).  And you can pass args in registers.  No stack required if you have registers.  With only one register, you could use it as a link register, but then you'd have no way to pass args.  Still, without indirect addressing, you probably just use static storage for everything.

Comment: @PeterCordes You still need some sort of stack if you want to support recursive functions. A link register only lets you call leaf functions for "free", otherwise you need save the return address somewhere, and to allow recursive functions that needs to be some sort of stack-like FILO data structure.

Comment: @RossRidge: absolutely.  But note that the OP didn't ask for *recursive* functions, just functions (presumably to allow limited code reuse instead of having to inline a block at every "call" site).  Also, *if* the ISA can implement any kind of stack-like data structure, `bl` / `jal` lets you build a calling convention *without* needing single-instruction hardware stack push/pop logic.  e.g. the stack pointer could maybe be stored at a fixed memory address, and JAL lets you make function calls without needing to read, update and dereference it in hardware.

Comment: MIPS even has some registers that can be asynchronously clobbered by the OS, so you could use that idea to implement interrupt handlers without any hardware push of return info, just register copying.  (But not with 1 accumulator; registers that can be async clobbered are not useful for anything except when interrupts are disabled.)

Comment: If I use the accumulator to store the return address, then how could I perform other operation (which needs the accumulator too)? Seing my topic is 'on hold', what information do you need to know exactly what to answer?

Comment: Having just accumulator sounds ridiculously limiting. Even the early 8b CPUs like [Motorola 6800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800) (two accumulators only) and [MOS 6502](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502) (one accumulator only) had also indexing registers to allow for indirect memory operations. With your design I'm afraid (a quick Turing-based guess-timation) most of the calculation would have to be done on the compiler side, i.e. you would need huge ROM, as the missing registers/features would have to be replaced by additional (probably lot of) instructions.

Comment: Actually this makes me even wonder, if your design is even Turing-machine complete. Maybe start there, as I guess most of the people here will naturally expect that and use [sub]consciously the Turing theory to base their assumptions and advice, which will be invalid, if your design is not capable to support Turing-machine features. (for example on Turing machine you can freely trade instructions for storage and back, so even with no storage you can create the same code, just in instructions (but the code will be [almost] infinitely huge then = not practical))

Comment: I have just an accumulator because I wanted to keep it simple. I think the architecture is viable and it can perform basic operation like loading A, storing A, and, or, not, left shifting, addition, substraction and jumps. I used this architecture http://www.bigmessowires.com/nibbler/, but adapted to 8-bit instead of 4-bit, which is working.

Comment: @Ardakaniz - assuming a "nibbler" like instruction set, there's no equivalent to return. Instead something similar to Fortran's computed goto could be used. A value is loaded from RAM into the accumulator, followed by a pattern of ADDI, JZ, ADDI, JZ, ... instructions to jump to one of 16 possible fixed locations based on the value loaded from RAM. The 16 fixed locations could be LD (from one of 16 possible RAM locations), JMP to a common address sequences to implement something similar to indexing.